# Making a checkbox appear at the bottom of the unordered list when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

http://jsfiddle.net/AGinther/ZF7bD/1/

I am trying to make a list item appear at the bottom of the list when a checkbox is clicked using jQuery, currently I have;

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1"><label for="checkbox-1"> Checkbox 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2"><label for="checkbox-2"> Checkbox 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3"><label for="checkbox-3"> Checkbox 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4"><label for="checkbox-4"> Checkbox 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
     //Some code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: I think the question is quite clear it also has a clear answer - why should this deserve a close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to include jQuery as a library in your fiddle. Furthermore, your `if` statement doesn't bind to any events.

You can do this by binding to the click event for checkboxes.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.is(':checked')) {
        var cb = $t.parent().remove();
        $('ul').append(cb);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF7bD/7/